# Use the recursive definition of summation together with mathematical induction to prove a sequence

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Use the recursive definition of summation together with mathematical induction to prove that for all positive integers n, if a1, a2, ... , an and b1, b2, ... , bn are real numbers, then
n              n     n
∑(2ak −3bk) = 2∑ak −3∑bk.
k=1            k=1   k=1

Comment: Please use [$\rm \LaTeX$](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  What have you tried?

Comment: Go to Help on the top bar,  On the Help page, under Our Model, click on How Do I Format Mathematics Here? and  from there, also, the Quick Reference Guide. Your last formula , as written, is unintelligible to me.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first check the base case:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^1 (2a_k-3b_k) = 2a_1-3b_1 = 2\sum_{k = 1}^1 a_k-3\sum_{k = 1}^1 b_k$$
So, we've verified our base case.
Now, assume the $n$th case holds.
So, we have that:
$$\sum_{k = 1}^n (2a_k-3b_k) = 2\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k-3\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k$$
Now, try adding $2a_{n+1}-3b_{n+1}$ to both sides.  We get that:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k = 1}^n (2a_k-3b_k)+2a_{n+1}-3b_{n+1} &= 2\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k-3\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k +2a_{n+1}-3b_{n+1}\\
\sum_{k = 1}^{n+1}(2a_k-3b_k) & = 2\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k+2a_{k+1}-3\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k-3b_{n+1} \\
& = 2\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n a_k+a_{n+1}\right)-3\left(\sum_{k = 1}^n b_k+b_{n+1}\right) \\
& = 2\sum_{k = 1}^{n+1}a_k-3\sum_{k = 1}^{n+1}b_k
\end{align*}